# Is "constructed of" synonymous with "constructed with"

Tags: grammar

The above comes from a Wikipedia article:

> It was constructed of woven layers of curtains and wood, and richly
>   furnished with valuable materials taken from Egypt.

I am wondering if "constructed of" means the same thing as "constructed with". I am not sure if I am crazy, but it sounds wrong. Is it? What do you think about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare these two sentences:

> My house was built **with** (**using / by**) a hammer, saw, and level.
>   My house was built **from** (**of / out of**) wood, metal, and insulation.

I used *built* rather than *constructed* because the distinction is more easily seen with the different verb, but the principle is the same.

Typically, when you build or construct something *with* something, the preposition *with* refers to the tools that you used; when you build or construct something *from* something, the preposition *from* refers to the materials out of which it's made.

---

Although it's likely you could determine the meaning of the sentence from context, and it's possible that *with* could be taken in the same sense as *of*, the two are not commonly used synonymously in this construction.

Comment: Does built of means that the materials enumerated are all of the materials that were used?

Comment: @repomonster Most likely not. A lot more material goes into construction that what would commonly be listed. But it's the main materials that are given. In the fairy tale [*The Three Little Pigs*](https://americanliterature.com/childrens-stories/the-three-little-pigs), I'm sure that the houses were built of more than just straw, sticks, and brick. (The brick house would have also been built of mortar, for instance.)

Answer (score 1):

I am not a native speaker, but i am going to give my response, though.

There nothing wrong with using **of** with constructed.

Basically, if you look this word up on an OXFORD dictionary, you will definitely see “of” follow [construct](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/construct_1).

Both work, but the meaning is a bit slightly different to me.

If you say:

> - your rooms is constructed of wood.

Here, it gives the meaning that you whole entire room is made out of wood.

But, if you say that

> - your room is constructed with wood.

Here, i can understand that some parts of your room are wooden.

---

Honestly though, i will be waiting for a native speaker to confirm or refute what has been explained in my answer.